# Upload a file using the post node in Knime

Tags: knime

I have a post endpoint that will accept some parameters like `file` and `name` in order for me to upload a file. I want to achieve this using [Knime](https://www.knime.com/) but I'm not sure how I can pass the file data to the post node.

What would be a minimal Knime flow that can read the data from a local file and
prepare it for the post node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads are typically done with so-called “multipart encoding”.

You can use the [HTTP Retriever](https://nodepit.com/node/ws.palladian.nodes.retrieval.HttpRetrieverNodeFactory2) and its companion node [Multipart Encoded HTTP Entity Creator](https://nodepit.com/node/ws.palladian.nodes.retrieval.utils.multipart.MultipartEncodedHttpEntityCreatorNodeFactory) from the [Palladian](https://nodepit.com/product/palladian) package for that. Palladian is a versatile extension which provides nodes for text classification, HTML parsing, HTTP requests, and geo data extraction which is freely available for the free KNIME versions.

An example workflow how to do a file upload using the mentioned nodes can be found at the following URL on my NodePit Space:

https://nodepit.com/workflow/com.nodepit.space/qqilihq/public/Palladian/HttpRetriever_Multipart_Example.knwf